# Javascript - Why time in ISO8601 format shows in 2 different formats at console.log?

Tags: javascript, datetime, formatdatetime

I have date in ISO8601 format, e.g. '2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'. I try console.log it as part of string and as variable - I get two different results:

2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z - when I show it as variable

Fri Jan 01 2021 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) - when I show it as part of string

How could I show date in ISO8601 format '2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' as part of string?

```js
let date = new Date(2021, 0, (1 + (1 - 1) * 7), 1);

console.log('Show as variable: ', date);
console.log(`Show as part of string: ${date}`);
```

edited: set proper date format.

Comment: UTC isn't a "format" btw. Are you asking about ISO 8601?

Comment: Use `date.toISOString()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: thanks @Dai. Yes, it's about ISO8601 date format.

Comment: You don't "have a date in ISO8601 format", you have a date. You're logging two different things: the console's representation of an object (whatever that might be), and the `toString` representation of that object.

Comment: thanks guys, @Dai resolve problem, it works fine with toISOString()

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it depends on each runtime's implementation of `console.log`. The template literal (your second example) would do the interpolation of the template before passing the whole thing to `console.log`, hence it will be a string already when logging (and it would use the same value as `date.toString()`), whereas the first variant passes a string literal and then an object, which isn't necessarily a string as well (and it's up to the console to decide how to display it; think of how you usually have more convenient display options for arrays, objects and so on).

Chrome seems to not care and shows both variants the same, whereas Firefox shows the first one as a `Date` instance. Node's CLI kind of behaves like Firefox and shows them differently, but doesn't show that the type is `Date`.

Comment: I note that the ECMAScript spec didn't specify the format of `Date.toString` until _ECMAScript 9_ in 2018. It doesn't surprise me that browsers and JS engines today in 2021 still don't implement the spec fully.